# Putting an Glyphicons in-front of a nav bar item in Bootstrap3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a nav bar with some items. I want to put some Glyphicons in-front of these items. Is these a way to do this? I tried . But alignment goes off and i don't know a way to fix it. CSS doesn't seem to help either. I'm posting my Navigation bar coding here. Help me on this.

```
<div class ="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">


            <a href="/pos/system/main/" class="navbar-brand"> POS Admin Panel </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li> </i> <div  id="txt" style="color:#ffffff; padding-top:16px; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px;"> </div> </li>
                    <li class="active"> <a href ="/pos/system/main/">Home</a> </li>
                    <li><a href ="/pos/system/main/">Itme2</a> </li>
                    <li><a href ="/pos/system/main/">Itme3</a> </li>
                    <li><a href ="/pos/system/main/">Itme4</a> </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your code and put it on Bootply, does this work for you? http://www.bootply.com/A3JqV0m5qd

Comment: Hey,I just looked into your code and modified my code. Now it works fine. Icons are in the correct place. Thank you so much.